# Python/Regex - Best way to parse text description

Tags: python, regex

Say I have text strings like this:

- Fujitsu LifeBook E734 13.3" i5 2.5GHz/4Gb RAM/500Gb SSHD Like NEW
- Mac Pro, Early 2009 4-Core 2.66GHz Intel Xeon/16Gb RAM/1Tb HD

And I want to parse into Make, Model, Processor, Screen size, HD Size, RAM, Condition

I'm wondering, what's the most pythonic way to parse these strings?

Currently, I'm doing the following:

1. Iterate over static list of computer Makes and Models

   - If match, pull those out of the string
2. Split string by " " and "/".
3. Use `is x in y` to:

   - look for '"' and "in." to find size.
   - look for "GHz" to find processor speed.
   - look for 'Mb', 'Gb','Tb'.

Here's some sample code:

```
import re
data={}
complist = {'make':['Apple','Toshiba','HP', 'Fujitsu'...],
            'model':['Air','Surface','Zenbook','Lifebook','Mac Pro',...],
            'condition':['New','Used','Refurbished'...]}

string = 'Fujitsu LifeBook E734 13.3" i5 2.5GHz/4Gb RAM/500Gb SSHD Like NEW'
for comparison in complist :
    for compare in complist[comparison]:
        if compare in string:
            data[comparison]=compare
            string = string.replace(compare, '')

stringsplit=re.findall(r"[\w']+", string )

for i,s in enumerate(stringsplit):
    if any(key in s for key in ['Mb','Gb','Tb']):
        ...
        data['Ram']=...
    if any(...
```

I could brute force this, but the "..." are where I'm looking for some guidance. Also, the first portion could probably be done more efficiently as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you will want to split the `string` into a list, and then loop through it to see if it appears in the `complist` dictionary (instead of the other way around):

```
stringList = string.split()
for s in stringList:
    #loop through the complist to find matches
```

Doing so, you will be able to lessen amount of loops

**About list:**
Use sorted lists!
Because you will be able to use binary search, which is very fast

**About sets:**
Since it looks like you only need to find if the words are in the lists. You can store the complists as **sets** instead of **lists**. The speed of *membership test* in sets are O(n) ("Big O-notation"), and is faster than lists